# Can you trigger a Finishing Blow off both Compromise AND Unmasking?

Tags: l5r-5e

The dueling rules on P.159 of the core book states:

> The first time their opponent becomes Compromised or unmasks during a duel, a character may immediately execute a finishing blow.

Does this mean you get to perform a finishing blow the first time *each* happens or *one* happens?

EG. Tonbo Testdummy gains enough strife to become compromised so Kitsu killhappy immediately performs a Finishing strike. Unfortunately they are forced to keep enough Strife Symbols to become compromised their self. Tonbo-san Unmasks to avoid the dice penalty for remaining compromised and potentially get a better roll. Does Kitsu-san get to attempt a second finishing blow?